# Python schedule script running in IDLE but not in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, scheduling, visual-studio-code

The following test code runs perfectly in Python IDLE but in Visual Studio Code  I get an error message  that says:

"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'every' ..."

```
import schedule  
import time  
def job(t):  
    print "I'm working..." , t  
    return  
schedule.every().day.at("08:16").do(job,'hello')  
while True:  
    schedule.run_pending()  
    time.sleep(60) # wait one minute
```

I am trying to schedule a recurring task in Python. I've installed the schedule module and used the code to try it out. Cleaning chache, renaming the file and re-writing it in a new file didn´t help.

How is it possible that a script runs in one application and not in the other?? Does that make sense?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do:

```
from schedule import * 
import schedule
```

Print:

```
print schedule.__file__
```

**Also Be sure** your file name, is not named: "schedule.py"

Comment: yes, that worked, many thanks ...is there an explanation why it did not work before and only on VSC?

Comment: I am definitely not sure, but I think it shouldn't work in Python IDLE. Maybe different name of file?

Comment: In addition, I have tried to delete all files in the same folder that used the same formula and re-written the code. The script which failed  at the beginn

Comment: The script which failed  at the beginning now worked. Sometimes Visual Studio Code does some funny things, like giving an error message for a line of code that isn't there anymore, so my guess is it might have something to do with a bug in the program, since it is relatively new ...